# How Android Studio import the other project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am a beginner in android development,when i develop my app with Android Studio,i can use "compile" in `build.gradle` file to import the other project from internet like below:

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.phrase:phrase:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.andreabaccega:android-form-edittext:1.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.1.13'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.4.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.23.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1'
}
```

That's very useful, but where does those project come from? Can i import my project use "compile com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx:0.00.0" like above from internet? Maybe my question is too easy for you. But i really want to know why?

Comment: Post your entire `buid.gradle`

Comment: Ah,Just post buid.gradle to github?thx!

Comment: What? Are you asking me for code? You need to post `your` code in your `question`.

Comment: most of those are available on maven central

Answer (score 0):

Imported libraries come from the repositories that you mention in your gradle file, under the repositories part.

If you want to use your project in another one like that, you need to publish it on a repository first.